# Merge the data with the help of python or tableau

Tags: python, tableau-api

I have the 2 Excel sheets one have 63000 rows and the other one had 67000 rows which contains careers and their elgibility both have same title so I merged based on the title but the output shows me 44,00,000 rows why so , pls help me in this problem thank you,

```
Import pandas as pd
Df = pd.read_excel('c/downloads/knowledge.xlsx')
Df1 = pd.read_excel('c/downloads/Abilities.xlsx')
Df2 = pd .merge(df,df1,on = 'Title')
```

Comment: Please add sample data from both the sheets

Comment: I already tried that too I have taken 400 and 300 rows on both sheets it was getting around 6lakhs without having null values that too, how it is possible?

Comment: Could you please post the result of ```print(Df)```, ```print(Df1)``` and ```print(Df2)```? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create a list of the files in the order you want to merge
all_df_list = [df, df1]

# Merge all the dataframes in all_df_list. Pandas will automatically append based on similar column names if that is what you meant by "same title".
appended_df = pd.concat(all_df_list)

# export as an excel file
appended_df.to_excel("data.xlsx", index=False)
```

Let me know if this helps. Works only if you have same labels in both of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the correct join type. Left, Right, Inner, Outer etc. It sounds like you need to use a Left Join. That will match data from the table on the right to the one on the left and return values accordingly, similar to a VLOOKUP. If the default join type is an Outer join then it will include all values from both tables and will dramatically increase your records.